# Unable to execute python script using javascript

Tags: javascript, python

After going through a couple of tutorials and previously answered similar questions on stackoverflow this was the final result of what my code looked like:

```
function myFunction() {

  var data = document.getElementById("data").value;

  if (data == '') {
    alert("No command entered!");
  }

  else {
    alert("command entered!");
    // AJAX code to execute python 
    $.ajax({
      type    : "POST",
      url     : "/cgi/test.py"
    });
  }
}
```

These are the following permissions on my test.py file after doing a chmod +x:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         821 Dec 15 23:27 test.py*
```

I can run the python file successfully by doing "test.py" so it works as an executable just great. However for some reason when I try to run it using the ajax it won't execute. Can someone help me out with this dilemma; any help is much appreciated :D.

Comment: What do you mean by "wont execute" ? How do you know that? Whats the response of the ajax call?

Comment: When I say "wont execute" I'm going by the assumption that it didn't run since my python script sends a message to a serial port. When I run the .js I don't see the message coming out the serial port. Really my own way of telling if it executed or not.